# Access 2016 - RecordsetClone Error on a form constructed with a virtual recordset opens "Select Data Source" dialog

Tags: vba, dao, adodb, ms-access-2016

I've seen a number of posts trying to describe this bug but they haven't framed the problem correctly to be reproduced... or not set the scenario in the way that I've experienced the bug using a common technique.

The bug occurs when a form's recordset is set to a virtual recordset and then referred to by a DAO recordsetclone statement. Instead of the recordset being set to the form's recordset (via cloning), a "Select Data Source" dialog is presented.

We most commonly use this to add a checkbox control to a detail form for a user to select one or more records for further processing. I've used this technique many times in many applications but now it fails.

Note: I have confirmed that this code works correctly in Access 2010.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro with a 32 bit Office installation

To set this up and reproduce the bug:

Create a new ACCDB database
Add the following references to the default references:
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security

Create a testing table:
TestId, AutoNumber, PK
TestText, Short Text

Append about 10 rows to the table.

Create an unbound form with 3 controls:
Checkbox, Name: Selected, Control Source: Selected
Textbox, Name: TestId, Control Source: TestId
Textbox, Name: TestText, Control Source: TextText

In the form's header add a command button: Name: cmdTest, Caption: Test
Set the form Default View: Continuous

In the Form_Open call a sub SetRecordsource which creates a recordset and adds a column "Selected" for the user to check the records they want.

The command button cmdTest will attempt to reference the form's recordsource. It's while attempting to reference the form's recordsouce that the error occurs. Instead of the reference being made, the "Select Data Source" dialog pops up.

The complete form's VBA code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
On Error GoTo errHandler
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
' Using an ADODB recordset works but is an ugly solution
' To test comment out the Dim DAO and Set rs statements above and uncomment the next 2 lines.
'  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
'  Set rs = Me.Recordset
  rs.MoveFirst
  With rs
    Do While Not .EOF
      Debug.Print .Fields("Selected"), .Fields("TestId"), .Fields("TestText")
    .MoveNext
    Loop
  End With
  Set rs = Nothing
ExitSub:
  Exit Sub
errHandler:
  MsgBox "Error in " & Me.Name & ".SetRecordsource " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ExitSub
End Sub

Private Sub SetRecordsource()
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset   'the virtual recordset to hold the source data plus the boolean Selected field
  Dim rsSource As DAO.Recordset  'dim the source recordset

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  With rs
    .Fields.Append "Selected", adboolean
    .Fields.Append "TestId", adInteger, , adFldKeyColumn
    .Fields.Append "TestText", adVarChar, 80
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .Open

    Set rsSource = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select TestId, TestText from Test", dbOpenDynaset)
    rsSource.MoveFirst
    Do Until rsSource.EOF
      .AddNew
      .Fields("Selected") = 0 'set the checkboxes to unchecked
      .Fields("TestId") = rsSource.Fields(0)
      .Fields("TestText") = rsSource.Fields(1)
      .Update
      rsSource.MoveNext
    Loop
  End With
  Set Me.Recordset = rs 'Set the form's recordset = to our virtual recordset
  Set rsSource = Nothing
  Set rs = Nothing
ExitSub:
  Exit Sub
err_handler:
  MsgBox "Error in " & Me.Name & ".SetRecordsource " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ExitSub
End Sub 'SetRecordsource
```

Open the form and click the Test command button to reproduce the error.

One solution proposed is to use an ADODB recordset and set it to Me.Recordset instead of Me.Recordsetclone. While this does work, it's an ugly solution since you are now operating on the form's recordsource and when looping through the records to find the rows where Selected = True moves the current record on the form. Not only does the current record pointer move but if there's more rows then the can show, the user sees the form's records scrolling.

Any help, confirmation or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From another forum the solution to this is to use an ADODB recordset and then clone the form to it via Recordset.Clone. In the code above, it references an "ugly" solution:

' Using an ADODB recordset works but is an ugly solution
' To test comment out the Dim DAO and Set rs statements above and uncomment the next 2 lines.

'  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

'  Set rs = Me.Recordset

Setting rs = Me.Recordset will operate on the form (not desired).

But using an ADODB recordset and then
    setting rs = Me.Recordset.Clone works, does not operate on the form and doesn't pop up the Data Source Dialog.

Something has changed in 2016 but this does work and may help someone else.
You may also want to read: [Create In-Memory ADO Recordsets at Database Journal](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3846361/Create-In-Memory-ADO-Recordsets.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't work, as you try to assign an ADODB.Recordset (the one in `Form.Recordset`) to a DAO.Recordset,`as it is declared.

If the Recordset-Type can vary, you can dim`rs as Object`then it gets the type of `Form.Recordset`(by Form Property RecordsetClone, that surprisingly works for ADODB:Recordsets too). You can query the type with:

```
If TypeOf Me.RecordSet Is ADODB.Recordset Then
   'ADODB
 Else
   'DAO
 End If
```

If you need an unbound`CheckBox`, you can use`clsCCRecordSelect`-Class from [SelectRecordsV2](http://www.ccedv.de/downloads/start.php?download=SelectRecordsV2.zip&lang=en).

The`clsCCRecordSelect`is used by me for years and I don't want to live without!

Comment: I would prefer to use MS native props/methods. I appreciate the SelectRecords2 suggestion & will check it out. The CheckBox needs to be bound to each row of the continuous form to determine which specific row is selected. If unbound, it will apply to all rows. 


Form recordsets are DAO and I've never had a problem using recordsetclone to clone a form recordset to an ADODB recordset. LOTS of examples use this method. Again, this works just fine in 2010. I've used it for years w/o fail. Only in 2016 does it oddly pop the Select Data Source dialog. I hope someone will play with the example.

Comment: The Checkbox is unbound, but indiependent and the class is aware of the status of each box. Just a public declaration of the Instance and an init on From_Load is needed. Have a look at the sample db. RecordSetClone shouldn't work with AdoDb and you can't assing a AdoDb.Recordset to a Dao:Recordset, but there is a Recordset.Clone function for AdoDb.

Comment: Creating a source AdoDb recordset and assigning it to a form's recordsource works. It works in previous and current versions. The issue is working on the form's recordset after the user has selected one or more rows. At the point of error, we are working with a DAO recordset and a DAO form recordset. the statement: 
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
causes a Select Data Source dialog box to be presented. That is the error and reason for this post.

Comment: Check your object types and and add watches to rs and me to check them at runtime.